# Возможно ли перекинуть оплату товара с одной позиции на другую?

Tags: wordpress

Подробнее...прошла по вукомерсу оплата за одну позицию, и нужно перенести этот платеж на другую позицию..спасибо откликнувшемся

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce не предоставляет такого функционала.

Можно создать другой заказ на правильный товар, с оплатой при получении. Вручную в админке поставить статус "выполнено", а прошедший заказ на неправильную позицию удалить.